# Return Value From AJAX Outside AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want the html value of AJAX in outside of AJAX Call or in the  `$('#username').blur(function()` function.. Is this possible ?

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#username').blur(function() {
                var username = $(this).val();
                availibilityCheck(username);
            })
    
            function availibilityCheck(username) {
                var result = "";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: "availibilityCheck",
                        data: username
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#usernameresponse').html(html);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can use a global variable. Set the variable in ajax call, then use it inside `$('#username').blur()`

Comment: Ajax is an async call. So, add `async:false` and then everything is synchronous. But this is a bad practice. I suppose you can try `.done()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#username').blur(function() {
                var username = $(this).val();
                availibilityCheck(username);

                var return_first;
                function callback(response) {
                  return_first = response;
                  //use return_first variable here
                }
                
                
                
            })
    
            function availibilityCheck(username) {
                var result = "";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: "availibilityCheck",
                        data: username
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(html) {
                     callback(html);
                        $('#usernameresponse').html(html);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    </script>
```